# Nashorn exception when using HibernateValidator's ScriptAssert on Java8

Tags: java-8, hibernate-validator, nashorn

We are in the process of switching from Java 7 to Java 8 ( about time I think :-)) and we are getting issues where we used HibernateValidator's ScriptAssert. Looks like Nashorn Javascript engine is not initialized properly

The ScriptAssert is used as follows

```
@ScriptAssert(
    lang = "javascript",
    script = "_this.owner != null && _this.owner.id != null"
        + " && _this.owner.id.matches('^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[1-5][0-9A-
F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$')"
)
```

What we are getting is an exception like below, This happens on JDK1.8.0_131 on Linux.

Any help would be appreciated. Following is the stack trace.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeExact(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.AccessorProperty.invokeSetter(AccessorProperty.java:462)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.AccessorProperty.setValue(AccessorProperty.java:485)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.erasePropertyValue(ScriptObject.java:916)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.deleteOwnProperty(ScriptObject.java:928)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.createBuiltin(ScriptFunction.java:324)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.createBuiltin(ScriptFunction.java:339)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.createBuiltin(ScriptFunction.java:350)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeFunction$Prototype.(Unknown
>   Source) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeFunction$Constructor.(Unknown
>   Source) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.initConstructor(Global.java:2549)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.initFunctionAndObject(Global.java:2618)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.init(Global.java:2257) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.initBuiltinObjects(Global.java:1094)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.initGlobal(Context.java:1150)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createNashornGlobal(NashornScriptEngine.java:360)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.(NashornScriptEngine.java:143)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(NashornScriptEngineFactory.java:148)
>   ~[nashorn.jar:?]
>           at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(ScriptEngineManager.java:238)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.scriptengine.ScriptEvaluatorFactory.createNewScriptEvaluator(ScriptEvaluatorFactory.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.scriptengine.ScriptEvaluatorFactory.getScriptEvaluatorByLanguageName(ScriptEvaluatorFactory.java:70)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.hv.ScriptAssertContext.getScriptEvaluator(ScriptAssertContext.java:60)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.hv.ScriptAssertContext.(ScriptAssertContext.java:34)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.hv.ScriptAssertValidator.initialize(ScriptAssertValidator.java:43)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.hv.ScriptAssertValidator.initialize(ScriptAssertValidator.java:28)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.initializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:225)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:151)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:109)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:301)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:242)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:616)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:581)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForNonDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:543)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:410)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
>           at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:781)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

Comment: while I'm not entirely sure what is going on here... but did u upgrade the hibernate validator to the latest version as well?

Comment: Did you try to debug into this, checking which method that MethodHandle is supposed to represent? That being said, I think you'd be better of for your use case to use regular constraints and cascaded validation: `@NotNull @Valid Owner owner` and `class Owner { @NotNull,@Pattern(...) String id; }`. Unless you're using the script-based assertion for something else.